# Crear una lista con los elementos que no se repiten de un vector retorna resultado inesperado

Tags: c++

Me encontré con este ejercicio:

> Escriba una función genérica para cualquier tipo de elemento llamada
> vector_a_lista(...) que reciba un std::vector y retorne una std::list que contenga los elementos del vector
> de entrada, sin repetidos. Debe mantener el orden del vector. Escriba un programa cliente que genere
> un vector con 40 enteros aleatorios, utilice la función para pasarlos a una lista, y muestre la lista en
> pantalla.

Mi planteo fue este:

```
template<typename T>
list<T> vector_a_lista(std::vector<T>v) {
    list<T> l;
    for(int i = 0; i<v.size()-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j<v.size(); j++) {
            if(v[i] == v[j]) {
                break;
            } else {
                l.push_back(v[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    
    return l;
}
```

Pero no sé cómo retornar la lista. También probé el algoritmo de encontrar los repetidos en otro ejercicio y el resultado es totalmente distinto a lo esperado.

Podrían orientarme a encontrar el error en mi planteo?
Gracias.

Comment: A que te refieres con "*Pero no sé cómo retornar la lista*". Acaso no te esta funcionando el `return l`? "*También probé el algoritmo de encontrar los repetidos en otro ejercicio y el resultado es totalmente distinto a lo esperado*" Que resultados esperabas? Cuales obtuviste? Me gustaria ayudarte, pero faltan detalles. En genral, creo que la forma de ver si tienes duplicados esta incorrecta, pero no la he probado.

Comment: Si te fuera a dar una idea, ya que estas usando `vector` y `list`, porque no le añades un `set`. Pasas los elementos del vector a un set, eliminando asi los duplicados, y del set a la lista. Y para que sea un poco mas limpio el codigo, te recomiendo que le heches un vistaso a las [Range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for), asi vas a tener un codigo mucho mas limpio, y se te va a hacer mas facil de escribir. Mucha suerte